# Memory Management issue in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing a simple `UITableView` application whereby I need to display images in the cell. I am getting a memory management issue but is unable to resolve it.

I am getting the issue in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    SoftwareBugsDetails *bug1 = [[[SoftwareBugsDetails alloc]initWithTitle:@"BohrBug" rating:4 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]]autorelease];

    NSMutableArray *bugs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bug1, nil];

    RootViewController *rootController = (RootViewController*)[_navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    rootController.bugs = bugs;
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The error message is: `Thread1 Program received signal:SIGABRT`

As I am **using Xcode 4**, I have created a new group as `Resources` and placed my image in it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check that you don't have calls to exit () method somewhere in your program

Comment: @Chebum: No...I don't have calls to exit() anywhere...

Comment: The code does not have any calls to any `launchWithOptions`. Besides, it refers to custom class which may simply contain a bug that causes the problem.

Comment: I have only posted the code where I am getting the issue.....There is a call to the method mentioned

Comment: Here goes the entire code of problem:

Comment: [rootController.bugs release]; rootController.bugs = [bugs retain];

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but is your _navigationController set as "retain" when you define the property?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xCode 4 you must check the new ARC framework, It was added in Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5  but it has backwards support for previous iOS.
It will free your mind from releasing/autoreleasing issues so you want have to worry again for memory management (almost).

you can find more data here:
[TransitioningToARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-DontLinkElementID_6)

Or watch the WWDC movie about ARC here:
[WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/)